# How to align radio button list with text input list

Tags: jquery-mobile

With a my quiz creator interface, the user enters three answers then marks the correct one by setting the radio button:

http://jsfiddle.net/VLeph/2/

However, I cannot get the text input and checkbox to line up nicely. Preferably, I would like to do this without rounded corners between text input and checkbox. Like the horizontal radio group shown in the link below. But with text input on the left instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/CeN9z/ .

Do you have an idea how to do this?

thanks :)
Christian

Answer (score 0):

You can try placing all the text inputs in one cell in the grid, and all the radio buttons in the other cell, then use a bit of styling to align them properly.

Something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dA5Yf/)